# Setting the values in a matrix row from within an parallel sapply in R

Tags: r, global-variables, apply

I have a matrix (origmatrix), on which I want to perform a function per column. I want to put the results of this function into another matrix (newmatrix), with the row number of this row corresponding to the column number in the original matrix. In the real dataset there are 20000 rows with a complex function, so I'd like to use a type of apply in order to be able to parallelize the project. Is there a way for me to get the data from within the apply into newmatrix? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
origmatrix = matrix(1:50, 10, 5)
colnames(origmatrix) = letters[1:5]
newmatrix = matrix(0, 5,2)
colnames(newmatrix) = c("Identifier","mean")

boertje = function (x){
  newlist[which(colnames(origmatrix)==x),2]= mean(origmatrix[,x])
}
sapply(colnames(origmatrix), boertje)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using the multicore version of `lapply`, which is `parallel:::mclapply` or `multicore:::mclapply` depending on your platform, and then making a dataframe out of the results? You can make a dataframe when you return multiple values like so:

```
require(parallel)
res <- mclapply( 1:ncol(origmatrix) , mc.cores = 1 , function(x){ c( mean( origmatrix[,x] ) , sd( origmatrix[,x] ) , var( origmatrix[,x] ) ) } )

# So the first element of the resulting list looks like
 res[[1]]
  # [1] 5.500000 3.027650 9.166667

df <- as.data.frame( res )
rownames(df) <- c("mean","sd","var")
colnames(df) <- colnames(origmatrix)
#               a         b         c         d         e
#   mean 5.500000 15.500000 25.500000 35.500000 45.500000
#   sd   3.027650  3.027650  3.027650  3.027650  3.027650
#   var  9.166667  9.166667  9.166667  9.166667  9.166667
```

`mclapply` does come with this warning in the help pages though...

> **Warning**
>   It is strongly discouraged to use these functions in GUI or embedded environments, because it leads to several processes sharing the same GUI which will likely cause chaos (and possibly crashes). Child processes should never use on-screen graphics devices.

Comment: This works excellent when I need 1 value returned from my function. I can't seem to get it to work when my function should return 3 values tho (in this case, a coeftest from the sandwich package). I've tried using `newmatrix[,2:5] = unlist(...)` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @Xizam perhaps you could update the question to show how the values are returned in your function ( a list of 3 values?) and we can take it from there? If you have multiple values, do you want each one to appear in a separate column? I don't want to guess at solutions for you so it would be better if you could explicitly state the structure of the return values! :-)

Comment: @Xizam I have updated. Perhaps the edit will solve your problem?